# How to apply color palette to point shapefile in GEE, based on value of a property

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine

In google earth engine, I have a point shapefile as an asset. Lat / Lon, and a property (say elevation). I'd like to find a way to control the edge color, the fill color, and the size. Easy to do with the code below. However, I am really struggling to find a way to color the fill based on the elevation value. I'm familiar with how to do this for an 'image' (using palette and vis params), but I have run into a wall in terms of how to do with this with a featurecollection made up of a point shapefile.

Code is below. The csodata is a shapefile with lat, lon, month, day, year, and elevation. The simple code just plots blue symbols with black outlines

```
var table2 = ee.FeatureCollection("users/dfh/ms_shapefiles/csodata");

var vis=table2.style({
  color: '000000',
  width: 10,
  fillColor: '0000FF',
  pointSize: 30,
  pointShape: 'circle'
})

Map.addLayer(vis,null,'test')
```

Answer (score 0):

Map over the collection and assign a 'style' dictionary to each feature, individually, with the styles you want to override.

```
var colors = ee.List(["red", "green", "blue"])
table3 = table2.map(function(f) {
    var index = f.getNumber('elevation').divide(100).clamp(0, 2)
    var color = colors.get(index)
    return f.set('style', {fillColor: color})
})
Map.addLayer(table2.style({..., styleProperty: 'style'}))
```